# Convert GCC makefile script to LLVM 3.0 Compiler

Tags: ios, makefile, llvm, clang

I'm working on an open source project for the iPhone, and have converted the project to use ARC and the Apple LLVM 3.0 compiler. However, the project relies on an external library built using a makefile as it is written in C. Currently, it uses GCC to compile, and during the make it references the ARC-ified Objective-C code which causes errors as some symbols (such as @autorelease) don't exist on pre-LLVM compilers.

But enough about that. My question is how can I convert this snippet of code:

```
VERSION=4.3
COPT = -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${VERSION}.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${VERSION}.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -I../../ -I../../Classes/ -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin9/4.2.1/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${VERSION}.sdk  -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${VERSION}.sdk/usr/lib -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${VERSION}.sdk/usr/include/
COPT += -march=armv7-a -miphoneos-version-min=${VERSION} -I. -O3 -D__IPHONE__ -D_SNESPPC -DASM_SPC700 -DZLIB -DUNZIP_SUPPORT -DOLD_COLOUR_BLENDING -DUSE_SA1 -DSUPER_FX -DLSB_FIRST -DCPU_SHUTDOWN -DVAR_CYCLES
COPT += -fnested-functions -funsigned-char -ffast-math -fexpensive-optimizations -ftemplate-depth-36 -mstructure-size-boundary=32 -falign-functions=32 -falign-loops -falign-labels -falign-jumps -finline -finline-functions -fno-builtin -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -fpeel-loops -fstrength-reduce -funroll-loops -fstrict-aliasing 
GCC = /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1
GXX = /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1
STRIP = /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/strip
```

to use the LLVM compiler? I've tried modifying it to this:

```
VERSION=5.0
COPT = -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${VERSION}.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${VERSION}.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -I../../ -I../../Classes/ -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/lib/clang/3.0/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${VERSION}.sdk  -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${VERSION}.sdk/usr/lib -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${VERSION}.sdk/usr/include/
COPT += -march=armv7-a -miphoneos-version-min=${VERSION} -I. -O3 -D__IPHONE__ -D_SNESPPC -DASM_SPC700 -DZLIB -DUNZIP_SUPPORT -DOLD_COLOUR_BLENDING -DUSE_SA1 -DSUPER_FX -DLSB_FIRST -DCPU_SHUTDOWN -DVAR_CYCLES
COPT += -fnested-functions -funsigned-char -ffast-math -fexpensive-optimizations -ftemplate-depth-36 -mstructure-size-boundary=32 -falign-functions=32 -falign-loops -falign-labels -falign-jumps -finline -finline-functions -fno-builtin -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -fpeel-loops -fstrength-reduce -funroll-loops -fstrict-aliasing 
GCC = /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
GXX = /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++
STRIP = /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/strip
```

But this targets the i386 architecture, instead of the ARM architecture for iOS, so I get errors such as:

```
"i386/types.h" not found
```

Is there a special version of clang for ARM? Or am I completely missing something?

Comment: You have a iPhoneOS3.0.sdk and gcc in your include path down't ARC only work with higher OSs?

Comment: Yes, that didn't affect the code but I updated the question anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `-arch armv7`; you need to explicitly specify the target to build for ARM with clang.

Comment: Yep that was the issue. There's a new error now when compiling, but I need to do a bit more research into what exactly the error is.